# WebDriver FluentWait - can the Function/Predicate throw an Exception?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, guava

I'm extending Selenium's `By` class into a broader `Locator` class that can accept different types of location criteria and that will provide new methods to our version of `SearchContext` and/or `WebDriver`.

I have the following method which waits for a unique element to exist, be displayed, and be enabled:

```
public void waitForElementPresent(BSWebDriver driver, int timeoutSeconds) {
    try {
        FluentWait<BSWebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<BSWebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        wait.until(new Function<BSWebDriver, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(BSWebDriver driver)  {
                return isElementPresent(driver);
            }
        });
    } catch (TimeoutException timeoutEx) {
        throw new WaitForElementException(this, timeoutSeconds,
                WAIT_FOR.PRESENT);
    }
}
```

`isElementPresent` is a method which handles the check for whether the element is present (i.e. that it exists, is displayed, and is enabled), but without waiting. The problem is that `isElementPresent` throws a custom error `Exception` if the locator does not uniquely identify an element (that is, if more than one element is returned which matches the location criteria). There is currently a compile error in the above code since, as far as I can tell, neither `Function` nor `Predicate` are allowed to throw an `Exception`, and there aren't any subclasses that can either.

Is there any way to do this? Is there some form of `Function` or `Predicate` that *can* throw an Exception, like Java's `Callable` vs. `Runnable`? If there isn't, I guess I may just have to write my own version of the wait functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Does it represent a _programmer error_ if the locator does not uniquely identify an element?

Comment: It may. If more than one element matches the criteria, then it cannot be certain that the element being evaluated for "presence" is the one the programmer wanted. So I feel like this will help more than it will hurt. There's another method for waiting until one of any number of elements (which potentially different Locators) is present, so that can be used for situations where more than one element is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your custom exception throw extend RuntimeException instead of Excetion you should be able to throw it just fine.

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I only really became acquainted with the different between `RuntimeException` and `Exception` recently. Generally it seems more... informative, I guess, to use checked Exceptions, but in our project we seem to have a lot of custom Exceptions extending `RuntimeException` already, so this would clearly be a good solution. However, by now I've already written these methods without using `FluentWait`. Turned out to be about the same amount of code, even. But thank you for the solution to this.